# Change whole server's usernames with discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem with changing the usernames of everyone in a discord server. I'm using discord.js v12 and there are around 20 people in the server. I'm the owner of it and my bot has Administrator, but the bot changes the usernames only of the people that are in a voice channel. Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'username',
    description: "Changes the whole server's usernames",
    execute(message, args, prefix, Discord, client) {
        let nick = message.content.slice((prefix + "username").length);
        if (!args[0]) {
            message.channel.send("You didn't specify what to change them to!");
        }
        else {
            message.guild.members.cache.forEach(r => {
                if (r.id == '855161030119129090') // This is to not change the username of the bot
                    return;
                r.setNickname(nick);
            });
            message.channel.send('Usernames changed.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mass API calls falls under API abuse. Your client may be suspended from the Discord API

Comment: Here's the Discord API limits: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#global-rate-limit. tl;dr

`All bots can make up to 50 requests per second to our API.` maybe your bots already try to above the 50 request?

Answer (score 0):

The cache doesn't have all the members in the server, so you have to fetch them in order to get all the members of the server. You can do that by using the [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method.

Here's an example:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "username") {
    await message.guild.members.fetch(); // If you don't provide a parameter, it will fetch all the members
    
    // Rest of the code...
  }
});
```